# VirtualHost redirect 301 won't work

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, virtualhost

I've just updated my site (finally) and I need to redirect all the horrible old Wordpress style urls to my new urls (that is without the date prefix to each post) but I cannot get it to work at all.

This is my config

```
# Redirect old posts to the new ones with a 301
Redirect 301 /\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]+\/(.*)/i /blog/$1
```

And these are the target and destination urls

```
http://davemackintosh.co.uk/2011/09/fakepath-fix
http://davemackintosh.co.uk/blog/fakepath-fix
```

Why won't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

`^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)/?$ blog/$1`

**Explanation:**

- `^` : start of line
- `[0-9]{4}` : match 4 digits
- `/` : match `/`
- `[0-9]{2}` : match 2 digits
- `/` : match `/`
- `(.*)` : match anything and group it
- `/?` : match `/` optionally
- `$` : end of line
- `blog/$1` : redirect to `blog/the characters matched in group 1`

Using **RewriteRule**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)/?$ blog/$1 [R]
```

<sub><sub>Have fun</sub></sub>

Comment: Cool, any idea why mine wouldn't work though? I understand the regex but I don't understand why mine didn't work. I will implement yours soon and try it out.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh you have `/i` at the end of your expression, I assume you meant to use the `i` modifier to make it case insensitive ? But that's not the case here ! Your regex is trying to match `a date/anything/i` which you don't want ofcourse. Further I'm not sure if you should use `Redirect 301`, when viewing the examples [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html) they only use `Redirect`. Also it seems that you don't have to specify the delimiters `/` which means you won't need to escape backslashes either `\/`. (IMO)

Comment: Hrmm your answer didn't work, I'm sure it's correct but nothing is happening, going to check that Apache is definitely including the configuration file.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh I tried with an online htaccess tester and it worked. So not sure where the problem is, do you get errors in the apache log ?

Comment: I've just put a question on serverfault.com since I think this is slightly above me, your code did work via a htaccess on a test page I put up but I'm wondering why it won't work. Maybe it won't work through a proxy?